# Akka OneForOneStrategy does not work

Tags: scala, akka, actor, fault-tolerance

I have the following code:

```
class A extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 2) { 
    case _ => log.info("An actor has been killed"); Restart 
  }

  val b = context.system.actorOf(Props[B], "b")

  def receive = {
    case _ => context.system.scheduler.schedule(5 seconds, 5 seconds, b, true)
  }
}

class B extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def receive = { case true => self ! Kill }
}
```

After `self ! Kill` in an instance of actor `A` I don't see a message "An actor has been killed" and subsequent call to actor `A` generates "dead letters" message so there was no restart. Why is `OneForOneStrategy` not getting called?

It's strange in a way that I can just remove the whole `OneForOneStrategy` override and there are no changes in program behavior whatsoever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`val b = context.system.actorOf(Props[B], "b")` should be changed to `val b = context.actorOf(Props[B], "b")` to make new actor a child, not a top-level actor.

Answer (score 3):

You're simultaneously restarting the actor "B" and then throwing an exception when you restart it. Remove the `self ! true` from your `postRestart` code. Otherwise, what do you expect to happen? You're sending it into an infinitely recursive restart loop.

Here's the order or the actions you're seeing to illustrate it:

1. Create actor "A"
2. Create actor "B"
3. send `true` to A
4. send `true` to B
5. "B" throws exception at `true` message
6. "A" restarts "B"
7. after restart "B" sends itself `true`
8. repeat step 5

Comment: Ok, but what `maxNrOfRetries = 2` is supposed do then? I'm aware of infinite loop of course but I was thinking it should be terminated after two retries by parent actor `A` because of this very option.

Comment: @Anton Well, if `postRestart` was called that means the Actor was restarted successfully. So the number of retries was 1.

Comment: I still don't get it. The way I see it should work like this: start -> fail -> restart #1 -> fail -> restart #2 -> fail -> stop because `maxNrOfRetries = 2`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Anton The max number of retries is the max number of times an attempt is made to restart the Actor and is reset after a restart succeeds. It is not the max number of times an Actor is restarted.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've simplified my code and removed recursion since it's not really relevant to the essence of my question.